# How to stop .bat files from running in background?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch-file, fullscreen, regedit

I'm facing a strange problem after change the Screen configuration on my PC, the story is that before I identify my graphics card I used to use the CMD in full screen (windows 7), and whenever I run a .bat file it runs in full screen too, but once I've updated the graphics card , and got 1600*1200 resolution, the fullscreen is no more active, also all .bat files stopped to appear. Even when I run: Ctrl+r -> cmd, it runs hidden background (I can see it in process list).

PS: please note the the CMD from "Start Menu/All Programs/Accessories" starts normally (not hidden)

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Go to Start Menu/All Programs/Accessories, right-click Command Prompt/Properties/Layout/Window Size, Width=80, Height=25.

Comment: the command prompt from `Accessories` is differnet from the `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe` one, and the current oprions you requested is the same as you those you mentioned, thank you.

Comment: @MostyAmine If you select "Defaults" it will apply to all `cmd` windows. "Properties" only applies to the current `cmd` window.

Comment: @DavidPostill Where is this "Defaults" option?

Comment: @MostyAmine Open a `cmd` shell. Click top left of title bar ... select "Defaults" instead of "Properties"

Comment: @DavidPostill, it is set to Width=80, Height=25. and there is no full screen option !

Comment: @MostyAmine I don't understand. Windows 7 `cmd` has never had a full screen option. See [Full screen command prompt in Windows 7/8/10](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/full-screen-command-prompt-in-windows-7) for the reasons why.

Comment: @MostyAmine The best you can do is increase width and height to occupy more of the screen.